# Why is the kernel boot failing?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to boot from 3.11.1 kernel image on my system having Ubuntu 12.04 (kernel 3.2.0-53)

I used `make defconfig` and then compiled, placed the image in `/boot`, updated GRUB, and then rebooted.

On rebooting, I am getting the following messages :

```
EXT4-fs (sda1) : couldnt mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
EXT4-fs (sda1) : couldnt mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
init : unable to create device: /dev/kmsg
Root filesystem check failed
```

What went wrong?

If the kernel knows the filesystem is ext4 which I think it does because of the `EXT4-fs (sda1)`, why is it being mounted as ext3/2 ?

---

`/etc/fstab` :

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7be51edc-99ae-4e6e-b863-2bef9e4adb22 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=e4b936e5-e1c5-4146-9710-03b0d6dfdea2 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=10d012d1-bbba-43f4-8e8a-8aa493435acb none            swap    sw              0       0

# Move /tmp to RAM
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noexec,nosuid 0 0
```

---

`grub.cfg` entry for image:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.1' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7be51edc-99ae-4e6e-b863-2bef9e4adb22
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.1 root=/dev/sda1 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.1 (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7be51edc-99ae-4e6e-b863-2bef9e4adb22
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.1 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.1 root=/dev/sda1 ro recovery nomodeset 
}
```

Comment: Paste your /etc/fstab, please.

Comment: @schaiba Updated

Comment: Also show us this kernel's menu entry in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` please.

Comment: @terdon Updated

Comment: Did you generate the `grub.cfg` using `update-grub2` or manually? This is a complete shot in the dark but, does it work if you use `set root='(/dev/sda,msdos1)'` instead of `set root='(hd0,msdos1)'`? Does your `/boot/grub/device.map` correctly identify `hd0`?

Comment: I used `update-grub`

Comment: @terdon I dont see any `.map` files in `/boot/grub`

Comment: @terdon `set root='(/dev/sda,msdos1)'` makes no difference.

Comment: I just found [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Device-map.html) which suggests using `UUIDs` instead of dev names, try that.

Comment: @terdon I changed `root=/dev/sda1` to `root=UUID=<number>` which crashed on boot (caps lock led blinking). Did I miss some other changes?

Comment: Please post the `.config` (don't make us guess the `defconfig` for your platform). What messages were there above the ones about ext3 and ext2 that you cited?

Comment: @Gilles [.config](http://pastebin.com/7qxs5g53) Here is a [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6C48q.jpg).

Comment: what happens if you add `rootfstype=ext4` to the kernel command line?

Comment: if setting `rootfstype=ext4` works, then you may want to recompile the kernel with ext2 and ext3 disabled and rely on ext4's backwards compatibility with `CONFIG_EXT4_USE_FOR_EXT23`

Comment: @CraigSanders That got rid of the `EXT4-fs` errors. Didn't solve the `init` one, and so the system is still failing to start.

Comment: the init problem could be because there is no /dev, possibly because devtmpfs module hasn't been loaded.  BTW, is there any particular reason why you're not using an initrd?

Comment: @CraigSanders I am just using the default configuration. So, no.

Comment: ubuntu uses initrd by default, so there should be an `initrd` line for each kernel.  `update-grub` should generate it automatically if there's a matching initrd for the kernel.  i'll post my suggested solution in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to boot without an initramfs.  You need to create one with `update-initramfs -c -k 3.11.1` and then `update-grub`.

Comment: Thank you! [The OS finally booted.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91063/why-is-the-kernel-boot-failing) I am still getting a [few errors](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WW0Ia.jpg) though.

Comment: @AsheeshR, you need to enable devtmpfs in your kernel configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you've downloaded the linux kernel sources from kernel.org or somewhere and compiling it yourself, without taking advantage of any of your distribution's features (like packaging).

It's certainly possible to do this, but it's significantly more work than doing it the easy way.

Unfortunately, the ubuntu launchpad kernel-ppa doesn't seem to be maintained any more, otherwise i'd refer you to the answers at https://askubuntu.com/questions/47397/how-do-i-add-the-kernel-ppa.

Instead, I'll refer you to http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/09/kernel-3-11-1-released-install-upgrade-in-ubuntu-linux-mint/ which contains instructions for downloading and installing pre-compiled kernel 3.11.1 packages for Ubuntu.  I run debian rather than ubuntu so I haven't tested this myself but the page claims that this will work for Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 and 13.10, and the instructions seem correct.

Note that the kernel-ppa at ubuntu.com is an unofficial or semi-official repository.  The domain is owned by Canonical, but unofficial kernel packages may not be supported.  Neither would self-compiled kernels.

To summarize:

```
ARCH=$(dpkg --print-architecture)
wget "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.1-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.1-031101-generic_3.11.1-031101.201309141102_$ARCH.deb"

wget "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.1-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.1-031101_3.11.1-031101.201309141102_all.deb"

wget "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.1-saucy/linux-image-3.11.1-031101-generic_3.11.1-031101.201309141102_$ARCH.deb"

sudo dpkg -iBE linux-headers-3.11.1*.deb linux-image-3.11.1*.deb
```

If you prefer to compile your own kernel rather than download a pre-compiled package, I strongly suggest you search for the ubuntu source packages for 3.11.1, unpack the sources with `dpkg-source`, install the build-dependencies, make whatever kernel config tweaks you need, and build them your own packages with `dpkg-builpackage` or similar.

Just as with other software, a kernel compiled into packages will likely cause you far less trouble and grief than non-packaged...it's almost always better to install a package than `make && make install`, and even when you want to build from source it's better to compile the packaged source.